# Get the current window position under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, window

I want to get the position of the current window (its a console window). By current I mean the window I'm programming in, for example if the console is in the top left of the screen I should get X = 0, Y = 0. (By the position of the window I mean the top left of the window respective of the monitor)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int X, Y;
    GetCurrentWindowPos(&X, &Y); /* How do I do this? */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [`GetWindowRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519(v=vs.85).aspx), [`GetConsoleWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void GetWindowPos( int *x, int *y ) {
    RECT rect = { NULL };
    if( GetWindowRect( GetConsoleWindow(), &rect ) ) {
        *x = rect.left;
        *y = rect.top;
    }
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks! I had to do #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500. I actualy was lookinf for this function "GetConsoleWindow()" I didnt find how to get the handle of the console window! it helped a lot